# How to check if a function is differentiable (example from MIT)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Here is a problem from MIT, we have to find the values of $a$ and $b$ which make this function differentiable:

[image]

For this function to be differentiable, it must

1) Be continuous at $x=1$

2) Have the same derivative values from both sides at $x=1$.

But the solution from MIT says:

[image]

Here, we got $14$ from $2x^5+3x^4+4x^2+5x+6$ at $x=1$, so should not it be equal to $ax^2+bx+6$ at $x=1$ instead of $a+b$?

[Link of the problem and solution on MIT OpenCoursware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-9-product-rule/MIT18_01SCF10_ex09sol.pdf)

NOTE: Please let me know if such questions are off-topic here and I'll close it, I am fairly new to this website and am not sure how it works.

Comment: Regarding your note: this question is definitely on-topic for the site.  My only (minor) complaint would be that your previous paragraph ("Here, we got 14 ...") is not very clear about your reasoning.  (Also, "from MIT" is not very descriptive; do you have a link?)

Comment: Meta comment: There is [meta] for discussing about questions (is this on-topic? ...) and [help/on-topic] for information about how to participate on this site (what questions are on-topic, etc.).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$2+3+4+5+6=20$.

$f$ is continuous at $1 \iff 20=a+b+6 \iff a+b=14$.

Answer (score 6):

Let indicate

- $g(x)=ax^2+bx+6$
- $h(x)=2x^5+3x^4+4x^2+5x+6$

then we need

- for continuity $$g(1)=h(1) \implies a+b=14$$
- for differentiability $$g'(1)=h'(1)\implies 2a+b=35$$

Comment: No. We have $a+b=14$.

Comment: @Fred Yes of course I fixed, just a typo! Thanks